# Why the output difference between v2 and v3 permissions/list result

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I am very new at this.  So please be patient in my lingo and explanation.

I would like to know is this a google limitation or problem or am I using it incorrectly?

I am moving from v2beta to v3 for permissions/list call.  I see that v2beta result have more detailed.  I notice there are many missing fields, the specific field I am interested in is 'domain'.  When I run the v3 code (my backend code) it contains domain but the data is null, I am using fields=*.  I verified it with v2 API and the domain value is populated

As you can see there is no domain for v3 using fields=*

```
{
 "kind": "drive#permissionList",
 "permissions": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "id": "####################",
   "type": "user",
   "emailAddress": "#########",
   "role": "organizer",
   "displayName": "Admin User",
   "teamDrivePermissionDetails": [
    {
     "teamDrivePermissionType": "member",
     "role": "organizer",
     "inherited": false
    }
   ],
   "permissionDetails": [
    {
     "permissionType": "member",
     "role": "organizer",
     "inherited": false
    }
   ],
   "deleted": false
  }
 ]
}
```

For v2

```
{
 "kind": "drive#permissionList",
 "etag": "\"##########/#############\"",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/########/permissions?supportsTeamDrives=true",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "etag": "\"################\"",
   "id": "##############",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/#############/permissions/#############",
   "name": "Admin User",
   "emailAddress": "###############",
   "domain": "<the value is correct, just hidden>",
   "role": "organizer",
   "type": "user",
   "teamDrivePermissionDetails": [
    {
     "teamDrivePermissionType": "member",
     "role": "organizer",
     "inherited": false
    }
   ],
   "permissionDetails": [
    {
     "permissionType": "member",
     "role": "organizer",
     "inherited": false
    }
   ],
   "deleted": false
  }
 ]
}
```

What am I missing? Please help!!! Thanks in advance.

I have verified it with 
'Try the API'
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list
and
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/list

According to the permission resources, https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions#resource, domain should be there.  But it isn't.

Comment: Drive API v3 doesn't return all values. This situation is different from v2. In your case, how about using ``fields`` property? For example, when you use ``fields=*``, all values are returned.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I am using fields=*, else the API will even return less data.  The data I copied is for v3 and that is all that is returned when I used 'Try the API' and in my backend code, when using fields=*.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize I couldn't notice you had already used ``fields=*`` from your question.

Comment: I should of been more clear.  This was the URL for the v3 

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%[FILEDID]%22%2C%22supportsTeamDrives%22%3Atrue%2C%22fields%22%3A%22*%22%7D